# Question are not based on favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, interesting-page

When browsing Stackexchange with a normal browser you get interesting questions by the favorite tags.

Will this be available for the ios-app?

Comment: Makes sense, but I fear it's going to be technically impossible since the underlying API can't give the required information.

Comment: There is one sort mode based on your tags (Unanswered: My Tags) which roughly corresponds to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags (on SO)

Comment: + 1 This is definitely the most important feature for me. The app is really great but I have difficulties finding the questions I want to see (on the desktop version click on the SO icon).

Answer (score -1):

I wholeheartedly support this feature request.  Basically, without this feature, I won't be using the iOS app — it is no use to me whatsoever to see the whole list of all possible questions in all possible topic areas.

If this isn't fixed, I won't be using the app.  It is that simple — it is that unusable (to me).

The tagged questions option doesn't cut it; I track 54 tags. Granted, most of those show up once-in-a-while, but I do not find 'search by tag' really acceptable as a substitute.

Comment: this should be a comment. but i agree